# Android AlarmManager won't call BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android

I'm trying to call my `AlarmReceiver` which extends `BroadcastReceiver`. After I run this code, i can't see any of logs. Could you please help me in this issue. :D

Here's where I try to call `AlarmReceiber`

```
        public void downloadTweets(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();


        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {


            Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context,AppService.AlarmReceiver.class);
            alarmIntent.putExtra(AppService.SCREEN_NAME, ScreenName);

            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0,alarmIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);//getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);

            AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "shot");
            am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 1, pi);

            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "shot finish");


        } else {
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "No network connection available.");
        }
    }
```

and here's my `AlarmReceiver` class which is a sub-class of `AppService`

```
  public static class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

     Log.v(LOG_TAG, "AlarmReceiver"); 

     Intent sendIntent = new Intent(context,AppService.class);
      sendIntent.putExtra(AppService.SCREEN_NAME,intent.getStringExtra(AppService.SCREEN_NAME));
      context.startService(sendIntent);
      Log.v(LOG_TAG, "AlarmReceiver done");


  }
 }
```

And my manifest has this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.nutjane.android.rainalert.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<service android:name=".service.AppService"/>
<receiver android:name=".service.AppService$AlarmReceiver" android:enabled="true"/>
```

When I run, the log shows only `shot` and `shot finish`

Could you please help me solve this issue.

Comment: post ur manifest file

Comment: I've post my entire code. Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add:

```
 sendIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

in your AlarmReceiver class

Change your manifest file to:

```
       <application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
<activity
    android:name="com.nutjane.android.rainalert.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>

   <service
        android:name=".AppService"
        android:enabled="true" />

    <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="myintent" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


 </application>

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've added it but everything is the same.  
Please help me solve this issue.  :(

Comment: change your intent line to this:  Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);

Comment: Thanks again, I've changed it but nothing happens again :(

Comment: Yeah! Finally BroadcastReceiver is called. Thank you so much Kaijju. Btw, I got another problem, nullPointerexception. But I'll try to fix this. Thank you so much. :))